# Tensorflow error while restoring graph def from .pb file

Tags: graph, initialization, tensorflow, restore

I am following the wildml blog on text classification using tensorflow. I have changed the code to save graph def as follows :

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def,'./DeepLearn/model/','train.pb', as_text=False)
```

Later in a separate file i am restoring the graph as follows :

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join('./DeepLearn/model/','train.pb'), 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    t = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('embedding/W:0')
    sess.run(t)
```

When i try to run the tensor and get its value, i am getting the following error :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value embedding/W
```

What could be the possible reason for this error. The tensor should have been initialized as i am restoring it from the saved graph.

Comment: `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`?

Comment: But, i am loading the tensor from previously saved graph, so i don't think i need to initialize it using this statement.

Comment: You still need to initialize the variables, as reading the graphdef only restores the graph itself, not the values of the variables. If you want to restore the values of the variables you need to load from a checkpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alexandre!
Yes, i need to load both the graph (from .pb file) and weights (from checkpoints file.). Used the following sample code (taken from a blog) and it worked for me.

```
with tf.Session() as persisted_sess:
    print("load graph")
    with gfile.FastGFile("/tmp/load/test.pb",'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        persisted_sess.graph.as_default()
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    persisted_result = persisted_sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("saved_result:0")
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES,persisted_result)
    try:
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
    except:pass
        print("load data")
    saver.restore(persisted_sess, "checkpoint.data")  # now OK
    print(persisted_result.eval())
    print("DONE")
```